# Запятая при связующем слове (фразе)

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, однородные-члены, и, ссп

Затрудняюсь расставлять запятые в предложениях такого типа:
*В итоге она добилась своего **и** он ушел.

На самом деле он был счастлив **и** его девушка испытывала схожие чувства.*

Увидела когда-то правило и начала путаться. А возможно, такого вообще нет.

Никак не могу вспомнить правильный термин, но если есть какое-то "связующее/объединяющее" слово или фраза (вводные/наречия), то запятая между грамматическими основами не ставится. (Что-то из серии: "Она поняла, что родители ушли и брат остался один". Здесь придаточные части предложения, но суть примерно такая же.)

В приведенных предложениях по ощущениям разные ситуации. В первом одно вытекает из другого, а во втором части равносильны. И вот я никак не могу сориентироваться, нужно ли отделять их друг от друга или нет.

Предполагаю, что в первом предложении запятая перед **и** все-таки нужна, а во втором — нет.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как все-таки правильно? Спасибо.

Comment: В первом примере плохая однородность (она нужна для отсутствия запятой), а "в итоге" больше ко второй части относится, из-за чего разделять запятой не вариант. Можно так написать: *В итоге она добилась своего: он ушёл.*

Comment: Sharon считает, что "он ушёл" не входит в итог. Тогда она добивалась не того, чтобы он ушёл. Этот вариант тоже возможен. Тогда запятая. Какой вариант задуман?

Answer (score 1):

Да, действительно, такое правило имеется.

> **2.** Перед союзами *и, да* (в значении *и*), *или, либо* запятая не ставится, если части сложносочиненного предложения объединены каким-либо общим элементом.
> **1)** Общим может быть второстепенный член предложения: ***Вскоре после восхода** набежала туча и брызнул короткий дождь* (П.); <...> ***В сенях** пахло свежими яблоками и висели волчьи и лисьи шкуры* (Л. Т.); <...> ***В это время** тягуче скрипнула дверь сеновала и наружу просунулась голова деда Щукаря* (Ш.).

• Соглашусь с мнением *oleedd*’а в комментариях: смысл первого предложения двойствен. Для принятия однозначного решения — ставить запятую или нет? — нужен контекст.

*В итоге она добилась своего, **и** теперь я понятия не имею, что мне делать* (Елена Амеличева. Дом для мечты).
*В итоге она добилась своего **и** уже через пару часов машина принадлежала ей* (из статьи).

• Во втором предложении запятая не требуется.
***На самом деле** он был счастлив и его девушка испытывала схожие чувства.*

[§ 30. Запятая в сложносочиненном предложении](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=133#pp133) (Розенталь)

Comment: Второй пример неудачно составлен. Там лучше вообще "и" убрать. Вторая часть немного присоединительная. На нормальном русском языке написали бы так: *На самом деле они оба были счастливы.* А если второе отделяем, то оно становится присоединительным в некоторой мере. Поэтому не надо придумывать примеры, чтобы спросить о них. Это непросто, пишу с той целью, чтобы вы хоть немного уловили. Похожий пример: *На самом деле он купил молоко и его друг купил что-то похожее.* Не хочется "и" убрать?

Comment: Э-э... *oleedd*, а Ваш комментарий точно для меня предназначен? Я-то ведь ничего не придумывала.

Comment: Поэтому написано: *пишу с той целью, чтобы вы хоть немного уловили*. То есть чтобы умнее стали. И не только поэтому вам адресован. Вторая часть в некоторой мере присоединительная, то есть неплохо бы поставить запятую. А там мне ещё никто не ответил. Мне важно знать, какой там вариант.

Comment: И ещё пример: *На самом деле у него есть кошка и у его друга кошка похожей породы.* С "и" неудачно. Сравнить: *На самом деле у него есть кошка, у его друга кошка похожей породы.* Аа, это из-за того, что вторая часть ссылается на первую, нет независимости и нормальной однородности. Пример:  *На самом деле у него есть кошка, и у его друга есть такая кошка.* Без запятой некорректно. Улавливаете? В одну фразу оно не звучит.

Comment: А о придумывании — то в общем, то есть никому не надо так делать.

Comment: Искреннее Вам спасибо, *oleedd*, за доброе и, главное, тактичное пожелание — поумнеть. Так и сделаю, непременно! А пока — в связи с отсутствием должного количества мозгов — я ничего и никак *уловить*-то и не смогу. К величайшему моему сожалению — не́чем.

Comment: Умнеть всем надо, ну и надо друг другу помогать с этим. Не так оно и сложно. Просто читаться должно в одну фразу. А когда вторая часть ссылается на первую, может плоховато читаться (исходный пример, из-за присоединительного характера второй части) или вообще не читаться (пример с "такая"). Это если не вникать в детали. Надо отметить, что в первом примере нет такого.